# htaccess Sub Dir redirect

Tags: .htaccess, dns, subdomain

Is there anyway for me to redirect my subdomain index to my main domain?

From Subdomain.Domain.com/index  or Domain.com/SubDomainFolder/index to just Domain.com

Tried several methods from StackOverflow, but yet nothing seems to take effect. Thank you

Comment: How do you have all of the domains and subdomains setup? what's your vhost settings look like? do all of the hostnames point to the same server? Can you give precise examples of what you start with and what you want to end up with? What have you tried? Keeping in mind that "redirect" is telling a browser/client to go to a *new* URL, changing the location in the address bar, and resending a new request.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:subdomain\.)?(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:SubDomainFolder/|)(index)/?$ http://%1/? [L,R,NC]
```